# vxWorks cache profiling

Tags: caching, profiling, vxworks, powerpc

Is there a vxWorks API to find out for example how many cache misses or hits occurred on the L1 or L2 cache of a multicore PowerPC? I haven't found anything in the WindRiver documentation.

Does anyone have any other ideas to profile caches? Up to now I have only made tests with/without caches enabled, but I would like to have more information.

Comment: In general if there is a register in the PowerPC that has this information, then you can read it from vxworks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I don't think there is such register (or I haven't found it in the manual yet!)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I use vxworks on ARM processors) there is no API for cache profiling. For some ARM processors (like cortex a9) there is a PMU ((performance management unit)) that can be used to retrieve some cache statistics, maybe a similar hardware IP exists on your PowerPC.